# jquery mobile - CFML - playing swf on ipod

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page that plays the swf file in Firefox.  But I need it to play on an iphone, etc.  I researched using jplayer but don't understand it.  The only thing I get on the iphone is a banner with the file name.  The url is;
http://devm.jobsintax.com/main/login  and log in as Jason/Jason123

Click on "A Day In The Life".  Click on "Play Audio".

The current code uses player.swf and works in Firefox.

```
<cfset request.layout = false />
<cfparam name="rc.soundFile" default="" />
<cfparam name="rc.titles" default="" />
<script language="JavaScript" src="/assets/audio/audio-player.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/assets/audio/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>

    /* $("#jpId").jPlayer( {
        swfPath: "/assets/audio"
    }); */

</script>
<cfoutput>
    <h2>#rc.titles#</h2>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/assets/audio/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="24" width="200">
        <param name="movie" value="/assets/audio/player.swf">
        <param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=#rc.soundFile#&titles=#rc.titles#&bg=00447b&leftbg=00447b&lefticon=FFFFFF&rightbg=00447b&righticon=FFFFFF&width=890&animation=no&remaining=yes&autostart=yes">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="menu" value="false">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    </object>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You can't view swf (Flash) files on an iPhone, period.

Answer (score 1):

As stated you cannot play SWF or FLV files on any iOS device because they don't support Flash. You can however use a player like JPlayer or FlowPlayer or JWPlayer to help you use fallbacks (if the user can't view a FLV file then a HTML5 video can be used, or the other-way-around).

You can convert FLV files to OGG and WEBM for free with tons of tools, I like this one (it's a addon for Firefox): http://firefogg.org/

Here is a great resource for finding tools to help encode media in HTML5 compliant formats: http://www.webmproject.org/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Apple products running iOS don't support flash.  You could use the `<video>` or `<audio>` tags which are supported by apple products, however your video would need to be encoded in the H.264/MP4 format.  MP3 for sound should do it...

Place that video/audio tag inside your SWF object like so:

```
<object id="FlashPlayer" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param name="movie" value="/assets/audio/player.swf" />
   <param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=#rc.soundFile#&titles=#rc.titles#&bg=00447b&leftbg=00447b&lefticon=FFFFFF&rightbg=00447b&righticon=FFFFFF&width=890&animation=no&remaining=yes&autostart=yes">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
<object id="FPalt" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/assets/audio/player.swf"><param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=#rc.soundFile#&titles=#rc.titles#&bg=00447b&leftbg=00447b&lefticon=FFFFFF&rightbg=00447b&righticon=FFFFFF&width=890&animation=no&remaining=yes&autostart=yes">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
<video controls preload="auto">
<source type='video/mp4;' src="Link to your MP4 file">
</video>
</object>
</object>
```

This way your file should default to your Flash player, but if Flash isn't supported it will try using the HTML5 tags you placed inside

Comment: Do I have to determine what browser is being used first and code for all possibilities?

Comment: @Jason You should read a lot about this topic, the Internet is full of it. Then you will understand.

Comment: No you don't have to determine the browser, essentially if Flash is installed it will use Flash, notice there are two flash object tags, one for Moz browsers, one for IE, this is how Adobe tells you to set it up, so if one doesn't work, the other will, if none of those work, it'll display the 'video', you could put even more after that, just default from one to the other. Just these two cover alot, the only problems I've had is with older BlackBerrys which I have to get around to solving eventually. I try to never rely on browser detection and use feature support to determine what method I use